# npm run dev not working. Command `hydrogen dev` not found

Tags: npm, shopify, shopify-hydrogen

When 'npm run dev' I get this.

```
?  Command `hydrogen dev` not found. Did you mean `kitchen-sink prompts`?

>  (y) Yes, confirm
   (n) No, cancel

   Press ↑↓ arrows to select, enter or a shortcut to confirm.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUCtK.png)

Node and npm are up-to-date. I also tried opening a new terminal. I also tried deleting and rebuiding the storefront.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I just had to run `npm install` in the package directory to install dependencies, then it worked.